# What is wrong with this create statement syntax for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and I'm stuck on a simple problem:

```
create (machine1:host);
match (n) where n.host='machine1' return n;
```

The match fails. When using explain I see this:

```
The provided property key is not in the database
One of the property names in your query is not available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you run this statement in your application (the missing property name is: host)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for everyone's time.

Comment: I should note: I'm using the community edition, version 3.2.1 with the above lines as the first two lines used against an otherwise empty new database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know the difference between labels and properties.
A label is a grouping facility for Node where all nodes having a label are part of the same group. 
I think you should use Machine label for Nodes which represents machines.
And you should use host property to store its name value.

```
    create (:Machine {host:'machine1'});
    match (n) where n.host='machine1' return n;
```

or even better:

```
    match (n:Machine) where n.host='machine1' return n;
```

Comment: This differs from mathematical graphs, where a label applies uniquely to a single vertex. Also neo4j's terminology page (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/terminology/) is vague regarding properties: "property - named value stored in a node or relationship. Synonym for attribute." and "attribute - Synonym for property."